# Android Layout: Game Board

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have seen a lot of questions about game boards, but none seem to cover my specific problem; though I imagine it's quite a common one.

I want to design a game board, using Android layouts. The layout will have X rows and Y columns. It should be expanded to make best use of the space available, but all elements should be square.

I am targeting Ice Cream Sandwich and above,

The first layout I tried was GirdLayout - but this was quickly discarded as there is no way to distribute unused space.

Secondly I tried nested LinearLayouts. ex..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".GamePlay" >


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <Button
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <Button
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <Button
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But, as far as I can tell, there is no way to get the desired level of control over the width and height of the child objects. It *almost* produces an acceptable result in portrait mode when the row and column counts match, but in landscape the board is stretched - and obviously it would depend on on other elements in your layout

One suggestion I saw was to manually specify the sizes of the elements - this would work but it would mean specifying different values for different screen sizes, and would need to be altered every time the rest of the layout is changed - and I ideally would like to be able to take a single solution and use it multiple projects.

So now I've run out of ides and would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I haven't found a solution to manage this in xml, but it's possible to do this in code using ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener

I used a GridLayout to add the controls, the xml of which originally looked like this:

```
    <GridLayout
        android:background="#FFFF00"
     android:id="@+id/gridGameBoard"
     android:rowCount="3"
     android:columnCount="3"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_margin="0dp"
     android:layout weight="1"
     android:padding="0dp" />
```

I then added the following lines to my onCreate:

```
this.oGameBoard = (GridLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.gridGameBoard);
this.oGameBoard.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this.SquareIfy());
```

And the function SquareIfy() as follows:

```
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener SquareIfy()
{
    return new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() 
        {
            int width = MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getMeasuredWidth();      
            int height = MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getMeasuredHeight();
            int cols = MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getColumnCount();
            int rows = MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getRowCount();
            int tileCount = cols*rows;

            double sizeA = (width/cols);
            double sizeB = (height/rows);

            double smallestSize = (sizeA<sizeB?sizeA:sizeB);
            int smallestSizeInt = (int) Math.floor(smallestSize);

            for(int x=0;x<=tileCount-1;x++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Button b = new Button(MyActivity.this);
                    b.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                    b.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                    GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                    lp.width = smallestSizeInt;
                    lp.height = smallestSizeInt;
                    lp.leftMargin=0;
                    lp.rightMargin=0;
                    lp.topMargin=0;
                    lp.bottomMargin=0;
                    b.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.addView(b);
                    MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getLayoutParams().width=smallestSizeInt * cols;
                    MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getLayoutParams().height=smallestSizeInt * rows;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) 
            {
                MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } 
            else 
            {
                MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }



        }
    };
}
```

This worked to an extent, but as the GridLayout had a weight of 1, the height would always stretch to fill the remaining space on screen; meaning I was unable to centre the board.

To get around this, I removed the weight property of the GridLayout, and wrapped it in a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shellGameBoard"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <GridLayout
        android:background="#FFFF00"
     android:id="@+id/gridGameBoard"
     android:rowCount="3"
     android:columnCount="3"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_margin="0dp"
     android:padding="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I then changed the OnCreate code to:

```
    this.oGameBoardShell = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.shellGameBoard);

    this.oGameBoard = (GridLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.gridGameBoard);
    this.oGameBoard.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this.SquareIfy());
```

And in SquarIfy() I changed:

```
int width = MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getMeasuredWidth();      
int height = MyActivity.this.oGameBoard.getMeasuredHeight();
```

to

```
int width = GamePlay.this.oGameBoardShell.getMeasuredWidth();       
int height = GamePlay.this.oGameBoardShell.getMeasuredHeight();
```

And with that I have an autosizing, auto centering game board! :)